# ssh exchange identification error while running scp script from unix

Tags: windows, unix, ssh

i am trying to copy files from Windows server to Unix server ..I just run the script in unix ever and files are copied continously for 9 hrs with out any interruption.
Next day when i run same script, after copying certain files i am getting below error
Connecting to windowsserver1  ...
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
 Then I tested using ssh user1@windowsserver1 , its saying connection closed, but other servers are able to connect to windows server, SSH are not modified, all keys are same how it is working bfore  . Please let me know how to debug this problem

Answer (score 0):

Use,

```
ssh -vvv user1@windowsserver1
```

and post this question on SF not SO.